# X-Domain Post using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, xdomainrequest

I have the following block of code:

```
console.log(1);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://anothersite.com/deal-with-data.php');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            console.log(2);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                console.log(3);
                if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
                       console.log(4);
                       xhr.send("formType="+thisFormType+
                        "&mediaCode="+3478+
                        "&car="+carID+
                        "&title="+$('#title').val()+
                        "&firstname="+$('#firstname').val()+
                        "&surname="+$('#lastname').val()+
                        "&tel="+$('#telephone').val()+
                        "&email="+$('#emailaddress').val()+
                        "&postcode="+$('#postcode').val()+
                        "&add1="+$('#add1').val()+
                        "&add2="+$('#add2').val()+
                        "&add3="+$('#add3').val()+
                        "&town="+""+
                        "&county="+""+
                        "&optin-post="+$('#optin-post').attr('checked')+
                        "&optin-tel="+$('#optin-tel').attr('checked')+
                        "&optin-email="+$('#optin-email').attr('checked')+
                        "&optin-sms="+$('#optin-sms').attr('checked')+
                        "&tarID="+targetID+
                        "&campID="+campaignID+
                        "&subID="+subjectID
                    );
                    console.log(5);
                }
            }
            console.log(6);
```

So, everything fires except for the `xhr.onreadystatechange` - I never get the `console.log(4)` - I have enabled `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in PHP and the htaccess as well as trying a veritable plethora of Javascript post functions.

The problem is, as a requirement, I need to post data from a form on a server that has no support for Server side languages - to another domain to handle the data.

Any ideas? It's driving me insane!

edit: I've also tried it with `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://anothersite.com/deal-with-data.php',
            type: "post",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {
                "formType":thisFormType,
                "mediaCode":3478,
                "car":$('#car').val(),
                "title":$('#title').val(),
                "firstname":$('#firstname').val(),
                "surname":$('#surname').val(),
                "tel":$('#telephone').val(),
                "email":$('#email').val(),
                "postcode":$('#postcode').val(),
                "add1":$('#add1').val(),
                "add2":$('#add2').val(),
                "add3":$('#add3').val(),
                "town":"",
                "county":"",
                "optin-post":$('#opt-post').attr('checked'),
                "optin-tel":$('#opt-tel').attr('checked'),
                "optin-email":$('#opt-email').attr('checked'),
                "optin-sms":$('#opt-sms').attr('checked'),
                "tarID":targetID,
                "campID":campaignID,
                "subID":subjectID
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#submit').val('Sending...').attr('disabled','disabled');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("success call");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log("error call");
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

And now I've tried to enable it in httpd.conf as well: https://serverfault.com/a/378776/36601

Comment: As stated in the question: "So, everything fires except for the `xhr.onreadystatechange` - I never get the `console.log(4)`"

Comment: xhr.send should not be in the `onreadystatechange` callback

Comment: @Musa - ahhh, so how would I go about making this code actually work? :/

Comment: *"how would I go about making this code actually work"* take the send out of the onreadystatechange so you actually fire off the request. BUT if the jQuery version did not work, you have some other issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass `xhr.send` inside xhr.onreadystatechange. Do something like the following:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'myurl', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4) {
        // do some cool stuff
        console.log('You got a successfull request');
    }
};

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(); // pass your params here
```

Comment: I'm getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://MYURL/test.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://asite.local:8080' is therefore not allowed access.` now. But I've set `access-control-allow-origin` in `htaccess` and in the `php` file..

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST header also. Read more on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: I have set `content-type`, `access-control-allow-origin` and `access-control-allow-methods: POST` but I'm still getting the x-domain error :(

Comment: Are you trying to call HTTPS service from HTTP page?